# Load multiple configuration files in Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

I'm building a Rails Engine and right now I set all my configuration variables in `config/environments/development.rb` (within the engine itself, i can also overwrite it from the application later) and can access it from the application with `::Rails.application.config.my_item`

This file is getting big and some variables such as `config.title = 'Lambda Website'` could be placed somewhere else, I was thinking to make a `config/settings/my_file.rb` and just include it to be able to call it the same way as the `development.rb` variables but it's more complicated than I expected ... I tried a couple of gems that didn't work at all, maybe because it's an engine. I also tried to require files but it blows up too.

How can I simply split this configuration file easily ? Is there an easy way to include configuration files within an engine ? Both YAML/ERB solution are welcome ...

Thank you guys ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your

## app/config/initializerz/custom_setting.rb

```
#custom_setting.rb
YOUR_CONSTANT = WHATEVER
```

Then feel free to use this constant this anywhere in your app.

Comment: RoR drive me nuts. I didn't about this simple solution, thank you man ;)